couldn´t match type 'IO´ with ´[]` inside a do
Haskell newbie here :) . I wan´t to read iteratively an element from IO and, in case is present, delete the element from the list . In other case, repeat the reading till the element entered is in the list. I have the following code :
import Data.List (delete)

main = do
let initialDieRoll = [23,45,98,34]
strength <- askStrength
let dieRollWithoutStrength = removeStrengthFromDieRollLoop strength initialDieRoll
print dieRollWithoutStrength

removeStrengthFromDieRollLoop :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
removeStrengthFromDieRollLoop = removeStrengthFromDieRoll

removeStrengthFromDieRoll :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
removeStrengthFromDieRoll strength dieRoll = do
if strength `elem` dieRoll then
  delete strength dieRoll
else do
  "Please, choose an element from the initial die roll"
  newStrength <- askStrength
  removeStrengthFromDieRollLoop askStrength dieRoll


askStrength :: IO Int
askStrength = do
putStr "Strength : "
readLn::IO Int

But , when I request the new strength, I'm getting the following error :
Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘[]’
  Expected: [Int]
  Actual: IO Int
In a stmt of a 'do' block: newStrength <- askStrength
In the expression:
do "Please, choose an element from the initial die roll"
   newStrength <- askStrength
   removeStrengthFromDieRollLoop askStrength dieRoll
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  if strength `elem` dieRoll then
    delete st

What is the best way to proceed ? How can I fix the error, and which is the best way to request for the value looping each time if the value is not inside the initial list ? . Thanks .

If you do any IO in a function, you must give it a type ... -> IO something. A function .. -> [Int] can not do IO. A function .. -> IO [Int] can. This is only the first main issue, though.

But in newStrength <- askStrength, askStrength has the type IO Int . Are you referring to that point ?

Yes, so removeStrengthFromDieRoll must also have an IO type. You also need putStrLn "Please .." which does IO.

You can not use the let dieRollWithoutStrength : in Haskell variables are immutable. What you here did was create a more local scoped variable, that will simply have no effect outside that local scope.

What's the point of removeStrengthFromDieRollLoop? It's just an alias for removeStrengthFromDieRol.

Not exactly, but It can be removed . Working in the implementation, I needed a method to be called again and again that let me reask for the strength . At the end, I can just call time after time removeStrengthFromDieRoll, so the ...loop method It's true that can be removed

Here's some code that compiles. (I have not run it, though)
removeStrengthFromDieRoll :: Int -> [Int] -> IO [Int]
removeStrengthFromDieRoll strength dieRoll = do
  if strength `elem` dieRoll then
    return (delete strength dieRoll)
  else do
    putStrLn "Please, choose an element from the initial die roll"
    newStrength <- askStrength
    removeStrengthFromDieRoll newStrength dieRoll


askStrength :: IO Int
askStrength = do
   putStr "Strength : "
   -- You might need hFlush stdout here, I'm not sure.
   readLn :: IO Int

Some key aspects:

All functions that do IO, either directly or indirectly, must have a type of the form ... -> IO something. So, askStrength must have an IO type since it calls putStr. Hence, removeStrengthFromDieRoll must also have an IO type. Hence, if you use removeStrengthFromDieRoll in another function, that must still have an IO type, etc. "IO is viral" is a common way to state this.

If you need to print a string, you need something like putStrLn. You can't simply use a string "Please, ....".

When you need to return inside IO, but you only have a non-IO value, like the list delete strength dieRoll above, you need to bring that inside IO using the return function (or, equivalently, pure). Note that return is not the same as in C,C++,Java,... but in Haskell is only used to convert someType into IO someType, so that "pure" values can be returned ina  function that has an IO result type.


Finally, IO can be tricky at first to grasp from beginners. We all have been there. I'd suggest to following an IO monad tutorial, if you have not yet done so: there should be plenty of them around the 'net.

It's tricky but I guess it's a matter of try and retry. My background comes from recently reading (not practicing as much as I could) "learnyouhaskell" and "realworldhaskell".I'm just trying to port a toy project using Haskell.Whatever, your proposal was amazing and I really apreciated it. One question,if you don't mind. talking about return, in the third point, I understand that it's a door to get "pure" values into IO Values. How can you use this IO Values as a parameter of a non IO Function? using let? ex: think about newStrength ...let result = function  newStrength? function :: Int -> Int

let result = function newStrength works fine in a do block, but you need to get newStrength first, as you did in newStrength <- askStrength, and that can only be done inside an IO function.
